# Android c2dm registration Unsuccessful

Tags: android, android-c2dm

When I get response from c2dm there is an error in intent object 
req code is:

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); 
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "achalrajpoot1@gmail.com");
```

and when I get response there is an error:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    if (intent.getStringExtra("error") == null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error in registration ");
    }
}
```

if() condition is true why?

what are possible reasons for this error?

Comment: I dont think there is an error because it is saying error = null and does not contain anything

Comment: when there is no error at that time you will get error parameter value null in response.so instead of intent.getStringExtra("error") == null you can put intent.getStringExtra("error") != null

Answer (score 0):

From [getStringExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) documentation:

> Returns the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or
>   null if no String value was found.

Maybe you want to test whether the string is not null?

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
        System.out.println("Error in registration ");
}
```